# java jsoup - How to get all links from a href searching by a text

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a lot of this lines in a webpage:

```
<a href="City1/Waves321.aspx"><span><span style="font-family: Courier New">Title</span></span></a> 
<span style="font-family: Courier New"> (<a href="City1/River267.aspx">txt</a>)</span></li></ul>
<a href="City2/Waves761.aspx"><span><span style="font-family: Courier New">Title</span></span></a>
<span style="font-family: Courier New"> (<a href="City2/River767.aspx">txt</a>)</span></li></ul>
```

and i want to get only:

`City1/Waves321.aspx`

`City2/Waves761.aspx`

and so on... every ahref before "Title".

I tested with this code:

```
public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        String url = args[0];
        String address;

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10*1000).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href~=(Waves)]");
        //String linkText = links.text();

        for (Element link : links) {
            String linkHref = link.attr("href");
            address = url + linkHref;
            System.out.println(address);
        }
```

and it works for most of the links, but it misses the ones that "Title" is in a new line, like this:

```
<a href="City/Waves321.aspx"><span><span style="font-family: Courier New">
Title</span></span></a><span style="font-family: Courier New"> (<a href="City/River267.aspx">txt</a>)</span></li></ul>
```

I cannot change the webpage code (by the way :/)

How can i achieve this in Jsoup?

Comment: But there is a way to return the links looking for the the name "Title"? "Title" doesn't change and was looking to get the links looking to it for all of them. (In python i do this by re.compile("Title"), but on Java (started with it some days ago) i'm not achieve it. (By the way, City changes. I've corrected the code.)

Comment: And because Waves may Change in the future and "Title" Will never Change.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this -

```java
Elements e = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
e.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.attr("href")));
```